# Highcharts chart redraw while exporting

Tags: highcharts

i am facing an issue in the highcharts export. We have a custom download button and on click of that we are calling the Highchart exportChart which is redrawing the chart and is messing the chart . Can you please let us know how we can stop the redrawing of the chart while doing export ?

Comment: provide some code or a live demo for us to find the problem!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of your load function in event.

Answer (score 0):

You may have specified some events like "load" in highcharts option, so that events may be called when you export a chart. This may cause problems. Disabling the events while exporting chart, solve the problem.

[Official Docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.chartOptions)

```
chart.exportChart({type: 'image/png', filename: 'file-name'},{
    chart:{
        events:null
    }
});
```